# Logistic regression plot for NA data not converging in R

Tags: ggplot2, logistic-regression, missing-data, naniar

I'm having a problem in trying to understand and testing missing data. My goal is to use a logistic regression to help infer if a missing value is MAR or not. For this example, I am using the `OceanBuoys` dataset from the `naniar` package, along with `bind_shadow()` and good old ggplot.

From the logistic regression, we can infer that the `sea_temp_c` does help us predict the missing values in `air_temp_c_NA`, as shown below:

```
test <- oceanbuoys %>% bind_shadow()

model_log<- glm(air_temp_c_NA` ~ sea_temp_c, family="binomial", data = test )

summary(model_log)
```

So from here I wanted to visualise the model to get an understanding. However, my attempts are returned with a "model did not converge" warning.

What am I missing here? I would have assumed that `sea_temp_c` being a significant predictor of `air_temp_c_NA` would allow for convergence for the visualisation?

```
ggplot(test, aes(y = air_temp_c_NA`, color = air_temp_c_NA`, x = sea_temp_c)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method="glm", method.args = list(family = "binomial"), se = FALSE)
```